# Equal a.e. and differentiability

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, measure-theory, derivatives, examples-counterexamples

Suppose $f,g:[a,b]\rightarrow \mathbb C,\ \  f=g  $ $ \ $ a.e. and that $f$ is differentiable a.e. Does it follow that $g$ is a.e. differentiable and $g'=f'$ a.e.? If not, is there any good counterexample? By the way, I am considering the Lebesgue measure here.

Thanks and regards.

Comment: Suppose that f(x) = 1 in a to b. Can you see a g = f a.e which is differentiable nowhere?

Comment: @Paul Oh yeah. An indicator of rationals is not differentiable. Thank you.